# Recommended approach in C# to read from multiple locations in a single file concurrently and asynchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, filestream

I am working with read-only data files (e.g. 100s of gig) containing blocks of data ~64K each.  I would like to build an in-memory cache to service the 10s-100s of block reads required to handle each service request.

A basic async non-threadsafe read looks like:

```
public async Task<byte[]> Read(int id)
{
    FStream.Seek(CalcOffset(id), SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var ba = new byte[64 * 1024];
    await FStream.ReadAsync(ba, 0, ba.Length);
    return ba;
}
```

I can't lock on the FStream to make the above thread-safe (C# error "Cannot await in the body of a lock statement").  I can't remove the await without losing the async behaviour.  My current workaround has Read drawing from a cache of FileStreams:

```
    private BufferBlock<FileStream> StreamRead;

    public async Task<FileStream> GetReadStream()
    {
        return await StreamRead.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
    }

    public async Task ReleaseReadStream(FileStream stream)
    {
        await StreamRead.SendAsync(stream);
    }
```

Is this the best approach to building a multithreaded async-friendly cache?  Any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to post some code if you want some help on this.

Comment: If it is read only MemoryMappedFiles could help.

Comment: Have you searched about FileStream.Seek?

Comment: Updated to add code.  Files are many gig, cannot be loaded into memory.

Comment: The physical queries of course will be serialized, but if he assigns multiple read tasks in parallel, the OS can schedule an optimal reading order.

Comment: Although I think it is not a good idea to keep a 10-100 GB database in a single file

Comment: @hege_hegedus that was my thinking, not to mention OS/disk caches of previous reads.  Some disks are SSD as well.  Files are large because there is a lot of data, we could I suppose break things up into 1000s of 1G files but the question would be the same.

Comment: Is [MemoryMappedFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) not an option? Let the system deal with paging in the right bits of data at the right time and just act as if it's all loaded.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, MemoryMappedFile implies MemoryMappedViewStream which does not have a thread-safe .ReadAsync() any more than FileStream does.  My question pertains on whether/how to perform multiple concurrent reads on a FileStream in an async manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to build an in-memory cache

Are you sure? :)

Windows has invested considerable amounts of work over several decades to implement an extremely performant file cache built-in to the OS.

There are corner cases where you can do more efficient caching for a specific use case, but the vast majority of the time it's not worth the effort. I recommend measuring first.

> I can't lock on the FStream to make the above thread-safe (C# error "Cannot await in the body of a lock statement").
>
> My question pertains on whether/how to perform multiple concurrent reads on a FileStream in an async manner

You can use a `SemaphoreSlim` to act as an `async`-compatible lock. The syntax is a bit more awkward, but it works.

On a side note, I also recommend looking into memory mapped files.

Answer (score 2):

What it seems like you desire, is to somehow seek and then read the file at the same time. The fancy term for this is performing an "atomic seek and read" operation.

Windows and Linux support this *exact type of operation*. On Linux, there's a function called [pread](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html), and on Windows, there's a function called [ReadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile). All that's left is to go through the mess of hooking into these calls. Yeah, not fun.

I had this exact same problem, and so I made the solution into a library. Presenting, my library [pread](https://github.com/SirJosh3917/pread). It allows you to atomically seek and read at the same time, and is faster than locking on the FileStream.

```
using pread;

using var fileStream = new FileStream("my_file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

var data = new byte[123];

var bytesWritten = P.Write(fileStream, (ReadOnlySpan<byte>)data, fileOffset: 0);
var bytesRead = P.Read(fileStream, (Span<byte>)data, fileOffset: 0);
```